# How do I import androidx.work.WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Can't import androidx.work.WorkManager.
Working with Studio 3.4

[image]

Comment: have u added in your dependencies

Comment: What dependencies do I have to add?

Already done this(gradle.properties):
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add this and it should work. in your dependencies block in **build.gradle** at app level.

```
dependencies {
     //other dependencies
     //......
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.1"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You first need to add the work manager dependency in your app's build.gradle file within the dependencies block like this:

```
dependencies {
  def work_version = "2.3.1"

    // (Java only)
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"

    // Kotlin + coroutines
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"

    // optional - RxJava2 support
    implementation "androidx.work:work-rxjava2:$work_version"

    // optional - GCMNetworkManager support
    implementation "androidx.work:work-gcm:$work_version"

    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:$work_version"
  }
```

([source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work))

Just use the one you need and feel free to omit the optionals. Then you would be able to import it in your classes/activities. If not Clear your caches and sync your project with the gradle files and try again.